# Access remote server after running ifdown eth0

Tags: ssh, ethernet

I had a problem:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

I've read and tried [this suggestion](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/how-to-fix-pycurl-error-6-couldnt-resolve-host-mirrorlist-centos-org-2/#comment-39090). Our server is remote, we connect to it with `ssh`. After issuing `ifdown eth0`, the server stopped responding.

My OS is CentOS. How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what do you mean by your "server went away"? We can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @polym I am not access to it with ssh, our sites on that server not load .

Comment: @polym I think this means the server is no longer accessible via SSH because its Ethernet interface was brought down.

Comment: @JosephR. yes, it is right, what is solution ?

Comment: @zhilevan Unfortunately the only solution I know is the one [Braiam suggested](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148830/26909) and this requires physical access to the server. Another solution that might work is if you have out-of-band management on your server, you can use it to restart your server or possibly bring the Ethernet interface back up. On Dell PowerEdge devices, for example, out-of-band management is known as iDrac.

Comment: @JosephR. what is out-of-band management and how can I do it?

Comment: @zhilevan If you don't know what it is, there's a good chance you don't have it. It's a special [hardware solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) that allows you to manage a server remotely without the need for an OS to even be installed on the server. To tell you the truth, I only know about it in theory and can't vouch for its applicability in your particular scenario.

Comment: @zhilevan If you're leasing this server from someone, and especially if the server is actually a VM, the provider probably provides out-of-band management. Log in to your hosting account and see if you can get a console that way, or at least reboot the machine.

Answer (score 3):

The only solutions I see is that someone bring up a console and restore the ethernet connection, or restart the server.

Comment: So simple and yet effective!

Answer (score 0):

`ifdown eth0` disables internet connection for server.

If server has no internet connection you can not connect with `ssh`.

To repair internet connection of server you must do `ifup eth0`, but you can't use `ssh` to do `ifup eth0` because server is disconnected from internet.

You must go to server keyboard and type `ifup eth0`.

If server is far away you can ask someone near server to type `ifup eth0` and then you can use `ssh` again.